# Where can I find the links/calls to AngularJS components for an app?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, moodle

From a previous question I posted I asked where does the index.html of an AngularJS app (Moodle Mobile) leads to when opened. From the responses I received I learnt that the app will call the templates from `moodlemobile-phonegapbuild/core/components/login/templates/` to form the login page.

My question is, **how and where is it declared that the application will load the `.html` files from `moodlemobile-phonegapbuild/core/components/login/templates/` specifically when I start `index.html`?**

For reference, here is the index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * filesystem: cdvfile: file: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com; img-src * filesystem: gap: data: cdvfile: file: https://ssl.gstatic.com android-webview-video-poster:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' filesystem: cdvfile: file:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' http://localhost:* filesystem: cdvfile: file:">
    <title></title>
    <link href="build/mm.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="lib/ionic/release/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script> <!--cordova.js will 404 during local development, as it gets injected into your project during Cordova’s build process.-->
    <script src="lib/angular-translate/angular-translate.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-translate-loader-partial/angular-translate-loader-partial.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ydn.db/jsc/ydn.db-dev.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-md5/angular-md5.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/moment/min/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jszip/dist/jszip.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/oclazyload/dist/ocLazyLoad.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-ckeditor/angular-ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-messages/angular-messages.js"></script>
    <script src="build/mm.bundle.js"></script>
    <style></style> <!-- Empty style to make easier to test styles using Inspector. -->
  </head>
  <body ng-app="mm">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see there are 0 reference to where the next "page" is. I did some readup regarding how ionic framework works and now I understand that the `<ion-nav-view>` will be controlling the view of the "page" like taking the individual `.html` in the `/templates` folder to form the login page.

But the question still remains, **where can I find the reference in which ionic is told to form the login "page" using the `.html` files from `moodlemobile-phonegapbuild/core/components/login/templates/` specifically once I start `index.html`?**

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know anything at all about moodlemobile but I'm pretty sure that the code you are looking for is going to be in that file mm.bundle.js

Comment: in fact, checking the source code, this is indeed the case.  it looks like this is already a full fledged app using quite a few different technologies;  I don't think I would recommend trying to learn angular or ionic by trying to decipher this application;  you should already have some experience with angular and ionic before trying to tinker with it's guts, just based on the number of other modules referenced in that package, and the size of that file.  It actually looks like some sort of build process built that file from a series of individual files in the original source.

Comment: as others have mentioned on the two other questions you have asked regarding this, you aren't going to find it easy at all to modify this code without some JavaScript and angular knowledge.  This isn't a web page, this is a Data Driven JavaScript Application.  and based on the size of it, it would take even an experienced angular developer some time to understand the logic before making any new feature additions.  I voted to close this question as too broad, because even just telling you the logic is in the `mm.bundle.js` isn't enough; we would have to explain that file to you.

Comment: Hi Claies thanks for your response. I am looking through `mm.bundle.js` searching for `login` and hopefully I can find out how the loading works. Unfortunately I have zero experience with angular/ionic/moodle but my internship assignment requires me to modify moodlemobile somehow so I am pretty much going in blind.

Comment: you would be better off taking a few days, going through an angular tutorial, then an ionic tutorial, and then coming back and looking at this code.  without understanding how those pieces work, you can't begin to make changes and be reliably sure that they will perform correctly when someone tries to use them and finds some way to click a button that you didn't even know did anything.  Good luck, just the same!